# What is the difference between Tangent Bundles and Trivial Vector Bundles.

Tags: differential-topology

Tangent bundle: $TM := \bigcup_{p \in M} T_pM$, where $T_pM = \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$. So, $M$ is an $n$ dimensional manifold.

Now, letting $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. A trivial vector bundle is $E := M \times V$. I know that this is trivial because we can identify $E_p$ with $V$ via $(p,v) \mapsto v$.

However, why can't we do the same and identify $T_pM$ with $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ via $(p,v) \mapsto v$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locally, the tangent bundle does indeed look like a trivial vector bundle. However, this doesn't have to be the case globally. A standard example is $S^2$. By the hairy ball theorem, every continuous vector field on $S^2$ must vanish somewhere. On the other hand, a manifold is parallelizable if and only if it has a smooth frame.

Comment: I think I am confused about when a vector bundle is trivial. I looked through several sets of notes but did not get a clear idea. Do you have a good definition?

Comment: @JeanValjean A vector bundle over $M$ is trivial if it's isomorphic to a product $M \times \Bbb R^n$. All vector bundles have local trivializations by definition. But this isn't necessarily the case globally as illustrated by $S^2$.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thanks! +1 and accepted.

Comment: @JeanValjean Happy to help.